# "Cherish" or "treasure" an opportunity?

Tags: expressions

In your application to a graduate school or a job position, would you write a statement like:

> I hope I could have an opportunity to ...,  and would cherish or treasure it with my life, if you could make my dream come true?

Comment: Either one or the other. They both are very similar, although 'treasure' may have slightly more material connotations. Nevertheless, using both is redundant.

Comment: Neither. You can cherish or treasure something if you mean you will hold it in high regard (for a long time), but you ***guard*** something "with your life".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks! What would you write for similar meaning? How about "(I would) cherish it if it becomes true"?

Comment: @Tim: You should take particular note of the points made in godel9's answer. There *are* idiomatically acceptable ways of expressing what I think you want to say (for example, if you *really* want someone to do something, you could say *"I'd be eternally grateful if you did [whatever]"*). But saying anything like that would often be seen as sentimental hyperbole/exaggeration. It would almost *never* be appropriate in any remotely "formal" context. On a drunken night out, *"I'd be eternally grateful if you bought me another drink"*, perhaps. In other contexts, I suggest you avoid such language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cherish and treasure are synonyms in the context of "cherish/treasure an opportunity", and I would use them interchangeably. (@FumbleFingers is absolutely correct, however, that you don't "cherish X with your life".)

Having said that...

In my personal experience, letters accompanying graduate school or job applications should focus on how your unique talents and abilities will contribute to the team that you're applying to join. Talking about how much you'll benefit if you're hired or admitted does not serve to distinguish you from the numerous other applicants for the same position.

Comment: Agreed. For one thing, "make my dream come true?" sounds much too informal and whimsical for the purpose.